# Polynomial Induces Smooth Map from $\mathbf CP^1$ to $\mathbf CP^1$.

Tags: smooth-manifolds, projective-space

Let $p$ be a non-constant polynomial in one variable in complex coefficients. Let $G:\mathbf C\to \mathbf CP^1$ be the map defined as $G(z)=[z:1]$.

> **Problem.** To show that there is a unique smooth map $\tilde p:\mathbf 
> CP^1\to \mathbf CP^1$ such that following diagram commutes.
>   $$
> \begin{array}[rrr]
> \ \mathbf C & \xrightarrow{G} & \mathbf CP^1\\
> \downarrow{} & & \downarrow\\
> \mathbf C & \xrightarrow{G}& \mathbf CP^1
> \end{array}
> $$
>   where the left vertical arrow is $p$ and the right vertical arrow is $\tilde p$.

The continuity of $\tilde p$ alone forces that $\tilde p([1:0])= [1:0]$.
So, by passing to the standard chart about $[1:0]$, the smoothness of $\tilde p$ is equivalent to the smoothness of the map $f:U\to \mathbf C$ defined as

$$
f(z)
=
\left\{
\begin{array}[rr]
\ 1/p(1/z) & \text{if }z\neq 0\\
0 & \text{if } z=0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
where $U\subseteq \mathbf C$ is a sufficiently small neighborhood of the origin, so that $p(1/z)$ is not zero whenever $z\in U$.

It so happens that it is easy to show that $f$ is complex differentiable, and hence smooth.

**But is there a way** to show the smoothness of $f$ without going into complex analysis? Thanks.

Comment: You could decompose a complex polynomial into its real and imaginary parts, show that each is a real-valued polynomial function of two real variables, and then analyze what happens at infinity, but doing so hardly seems simpler than your argument, either formally or conceptually. ;)

Comment: Since $p(z)$ is a rational function with numerator degree greater than or equal to its denominator degree, you can use calculus to prove that its derivatives of all orders exist where you need them to exist.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments.